# Calculating total area of polygons that intersects with other polygons in Postgis

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I want to calculate in Postgis the total area of 'a' polygons, that intersects with others 'b'.

```
   SELECT DISTINCT a.fk_sites, 
   SUM(ST_Area(a.the_geom)/100) as area
   FROM parcelles a, sites b
   WHERE st_intersects(a.the_geom,b.the_geom)
   GROUP BY a.fk_sites
```

I need to do a SELECT DISTINCT because 'a' polygons may intersect with several 'b' polygons, so that the returned 'a' polygons appear a few times.

This works fine, I just have the problem, that not all areas are calculated correctly. A few seam to ignore the DISTINCT case, so that the calculated area reflects the SUM of all, even the duplicated 'a' records (even if they should be eliminated).
When I do a query without the SUM function, I get the correct number of 'a' polygons and while adding their area I get the right value.

```
  SELECT DISTINCT a.fk_sites, 
   ST_Area(a.the_geom)/100 as area
   FROM parcelles a, sites b
   WHERE st_intersects(a.the_geom,b.the_geom)
   ORDER BY a.fk_sites
```

Is the combination of SELECT DISTINCT and the SUM / GROUP BY not correct?

Comment: Note if your parcelles overlap, you many need to use `ST_Union(a.the_geom)`, which usually increase the calculation time.

Answer (score 1):

This may have something to do with you `fk_sites` column because the query itself should be ok, although doing a `DISTINCT` on a `double precision` value is never a good thing.

You can solve this by identifying the distinct rows from `a` in a sub-query, then `sum()` in the main query:

```
SELECT fk_sites, sum(ST_Area(the_geom)/100) AS area
FROM (
  SELECT a.fk_sites, a.the_geom
  FROM parcelles a
  JOIN sites b ON ST_Intersects(a.the_geom, b.the_geom)
) sub
GROUP BY fk_sites
ORDER BY fk_sites;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works like a charm and all values are calculated correct.

Comment: Sorry, but I remarked, that I get the correct values only, when I use `SELECT DISTINCT a.fk_sites ` instead of `SELECT DISTINCT ON (a.fk_sites) a.fk_sites` as You suggest.

Comment: Answer updated. But as noted before, without full details on your table definitions and relations between them it is often very difficult to trace an error to its source.